# Jenkins Kubernetes Plugin doesn't executre entrypoint of Docker image

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-pod

I'm fairly new into Jenkins Kubernetes Plugin and Kubernetes in general - https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin

I want to use the plugin for E2E tests setup inside my CI.

Inside my `Jenkinsfile` I have a `podTemplate` which looks and used as follows:

```
def podTemplate = """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: website
    image: ${WEBSITE_INTEGRATION_IMAGE_PATH}
    command:
      - cat
    tty: true
    ports:
     - containerPort: 3000
  - name: cypress
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: 2Gi
      limit:
        memory: 4Gi
    image: ${CYPRESS_IMAGE_PATH}
    command:
      - cat
    tty: true
"""

pipeline {
  agent {
    label 'docker'
  }
  stages {
    stage('Prepare') {
      steps {
        timeout(time: 15) {
          script {
            ci_machine = docker.build("${WEBSITE_IMAGE_PATH}")
          }
        }
      }
    }

    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        timeout(time: 15) {
          script {
            ci_machine.inside("-u root") {
              sh "yarn build"
            }
          }
        }
      }

      post {
        success {
          timeout(time: 15) {
            script {
              docker.withRegistry("https://${REGISTRY}", REGISTRY_CREDENTIALS) {
                integrationImage = docker.build("${WEBSITE_INTEGRATION_IMAGE_PATH}")
                integrationImage.push()
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    stage('Browser Tests') {
      agent {
        kubernetes {
          label "${KUBERNETES_LABEL}"
          yaml podTemplate
        }
      }
      steps {
        timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES') {
          container("website") {
            sh "yarn start"
          }

          container("cypress") {
            sh "yarn test:e2e"
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

In `Dockerfile` that builds an image I added an `ENTRYPOINT`

```
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

However it seems that it's not executed by the kubernetes plugin.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Based on your pipeline code, the final agent with `kubernetes` would be ignored since you set a `docker` agent globally.

Comment: @MattSchuchard but it's not! Inside `container("website") {` I can make some `sh` calls to explore the contents of Docker image that was pushed in `post` step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Define a Command and Arguments for a Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#define-a-command-and-arguments-when-you-create-a-pod) docs:

> The command and arguments that you define in the configuration file
>   override the default command and arguments provided by the container
>   image.

[This](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#notes) table summarizes the field names used by Docker and Kubernetes:

```
| Docker field name | K8s field name |
|------------------:|:--------------:|
|    ENTRYPOINT     |     command    |
|       CMD         |      args      |
```

Defining a `command` implies ignoring your Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT`:

> When you override the default `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`, these rules apply:
>
> - If you supply a `command` but no `args` for a Container, only the supplied `command` is used. The default `ENTRYPOINT` and the default `CMD` defined in the Docker image are ignored.
> - If you supply only `args` for a Container, the default `ENTRYPOINT`
>     defined in the Docker image is run with the `args` that you supplied.

So you need to replace the `command` in your pod template by `args`,  which will preserve your Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT` (acting equivalent to a Dockerfile `CMD`).